# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb_db failed: No such host is known

Tags: symfony, mysql-connector, symfony6

Why am I getting this error in my Symfony application:

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb_db failed: No such
> host is known.

I am running Symfony version 6 through docker compose.

I have this in my .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@mariadb_db:3306/jwt-auth-app?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.8"
```

I can connect to my database from a db client outside the container just fine and my container service is running fine.

I get this error when making this Postman request:
[image]

If it helps. Here is my `security.yaml`:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            entry_point: jwt
            jwt: ~

        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

                # activate different ways to authenticate
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
                # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true
```

Comment: This part is wrong: `mysql://root:password@mariadb_db:3306`. I'm guessing `mariadb_db` does not resolve from *inside* your container. Go into your container and type ping mariadb_db. That should respond. I'm expecting it not to, which is why you get that error

Comment: @Martijn I got `Ping request could not find host mariadb_db. Please check the name and try again.` However this worked successfully when using the make commands to generate and run migrations :/

Comment: I'm guessing that is from outside your container. You need to find the 'domain' for from inside the container. There are two routes: "public", which is you, from your terminal. And "internal", from inside the cluster. those are different

Comment: try `mysql://root:password@localhost:3306`

Comment: Use the name of the MariaDB container in your docker compose configuration